# QGIS Graphical Modeler - Using field calculator to add values to point grid

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, field-calculator, qgis-modeler

Using the QGIS Graphical Modeler, I'm trying to add values from a raster previously generated in the same model to a point grid generated in the same model as well. I know I can do it using another step (Add raster values to points). However, I just wanted to know how can I reference the raster I created in the above-mentioned model to be used in the field calculator. Here´s the expression I used:

```
raster_value(@Natural_Neighbour,1,make_point($x,$y))
```

The raster feature is correctly generated as well as the point grid.
However, the table of attributes of the point grid remains with only NULL values.

So I just wanted to know if is there a way to reference a Raster Layer (previously created in the same model) on an expression inside a "Field Calculator" algorithm.

[image: Workflow (QGIS Graphical Modeler]

Comment: No, this is not possible, see: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/30397#issuecomment-505699624

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @MrXsquared. I hope they make it possible in the future.